# Unresolved promises in form validation

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

I have a JS function - checkUsername - that includes an Ajax call. It validates a form input and also validates the same input during submission of the form:

```
function checkUsername(id) {
  var userName = $('#' + id).val().trim();
  if(!userName) {
    showErr(id, 'An entry is required.');
    return Promise.resolve(false);
  }
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',               
    data:{'checkUsername': userName},
    url:'/php/ajax/validation-ajax.php',
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    if(response == 'notfound') {
      showErr(id, 'This user is not in the list.');
      return(false);
    }
    else {
      clearErr(id);
      return(true);
    }
  })
  .fail(function(err) {
    // some code
  })
}
```

In the first case, it's called by an event handler. In the second it forms part of a switch statement:

```
case 'username':
  checkUsername(id).then(function(data) {
    if(isOK && data !== false) {
      // submit form
      $('form#adminusers').submit();
    }
  });
  break;
```

In the form submission case, I think the function promise is correctly handled. But presumably when the function is called by an event handler the promise is left hanging.

Does this matter? Even if I write two versions of the function, one for the event handler and the other for form submission, the event handler version will still have an Ajax call in it and so the promise situation would be no different.

What's the right way of handling this situation?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

The most important part is that you fully resolve a promise. Typically when you find an unresolved promise, what you really mean is that the error state isn't resolved. In your particular case, in the switch statement, it looks like the "good" state is resolved by submitting the form, but if there is any error thrown by `checkUsername` or the form submission, it will throw an unresolved rejection.

Ultimately, you always should have a `.fail()` or `.catch()` - depends on what Promises implementation you are using - at the end of any Promise chain to catch errors that crop up anywhere in the chain. You *can* have multiple.. in your case, you have the `.fail()` within `checkUsername()` which can resolve that function's promise with `false` presumably, but you should have another one at the end still, in case any errors are thrown in form submission.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case, `checkUsername(id)` function use ajax which already resolved all the promises. so returning ajax will only return the return statement of each function that will be executed like success or failure. all the promises are resolved there only.

But in case of `switch` statement, you are calling promise on the function that is not returning the promise at all. i.e. `checkUsername(id).then(function(data) {});`

before using the function you first have to make sure the function returns a promise.

So your `checkUsername(id)` should return a promise:

```
checkUsername(id){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
     // do something here
  });
}
```

Comment: I believe that the function does return a promise - at least the ".then" in the switch statement is happy whatever the result of the tests in the function. The test for missing entry returns "Promise.resolve(false)" and the Ajax call returns a jqXHR object.